# Webapp2 strict_slash returns KeyError: 'Missing Argument' for url with trailing slash when method has 2 or more args... Bug?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, routes, url-routing, webapp2

I've built my urls as such:

```
#url = /index/test/argument/second
# Maps to the Index handler's test method and passes in the optional arguments 'argument' and 'second' 

# So the handler function looks like this:

def test(argument=None,second=None):
   print 'test'
```

I'm using strict_slash from webapp2 so the handlers with a trailing slash get redirected to handlers without a trailing slash.

```
#url = /index/ redirects perfectly to /index
#url = /index/test/ # KEYERROR!!
```

So even though index/test is routed before index/test/second, webapp2 is ignoring the redirect for trailing slashes and returning an error because it's looking (too hard) for the second argument. I think it should recognize there is no second argument so follow the strict_slash redirect route.

This works in all cases except with argument passing. Any insight, anyone?

Comment: Do you have "name" arg? All such routes must be named.

Comment: I do, the route is named according to the method. Do you think that could be the problem? In this example, I'm creating three separate routes, but all have the same name. Let me see. I'll get back.

Comment: @DmitrySadovnychyi it had to do with the 'name' arg. I'm dynamically mapping all of the routes, and for creating the route name I was using  handler-method for each of the args instead of handler-method-arg1 and then another route as handler-method-arg1-arg2. If you add your answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you just need to set unique name argument for routes.